# My while True: loop is not continuing to loop like the first set of code

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop

Hey guys python beginner here, I'm working on a little adventure game and I can't figure out how to work my loops. My first one is in a while True: loop and continues to loop the code when the user input is anything else. But when same loop repeated on lines 20-34 the loop doesn't seem to work anymore, the script just ends.

``

## Adventure project

import time

```
while True:
    print('A man approachs you with his sword drawn and an angry look spread across his face, what do     you do?')
    print('1. Run away')
    print('2. Punch the man')
    fightOrRun = input()

    if fightOrRun in {'2','2.'}:
        print('Man: "Your going to get it!"')
        break
     elif fightOrRun in {'1','1.'}:
         print('Man: "Where do you think your going!"')
         break
     else:
         print('Not a valid input!') 
         continue

 while True:   
     if fightOrRun in {'2','2.'}:
         print('1. Adios loser!')
        fightOrRun = input()
        break

    elif fightOrRun in {'1','1.'}:
        print('1. I dont know')
        print('2. Im sorry')
        fightOrRun = input()
        break

    else:
        print('Please enter a valid input!')
        continue
``
```

I've tried adding the second half to the first while True: loop but it just results in the error on the second half being "Code is unreachable pylance"

Comment: The indentation in your example code is messed up. If it looks like that in your real code, I can understand that a code checker will complain. What happens when you run the program?

Comment: I just messed it up here, in my actual VS code its fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason the second half of your code is unreachable is because in your first conditional, all of the options result in either a `break` or `continue`. This will mean that all the code after it is inaccessible.

I suspect that removing the `break` statements would get you your desired outcome.

You can read more about it in the python docs on [Control Flow](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops)

Comment: Upon implementation of your suggestions the code just now never ends.

Comment: It isn't clear what the intended behaviour is of the code that you have presented. If you would like each loop to be separate, then you will need to ensure that they are indented on the same level so that the second is not contained within the first.

Answer (score 0):

the variable 'fightOrRun' is not defined in the second while-loop.
you can try to define 'fightOrRun' at first of this loop or just put it out of  loop.

Comment: If I do that, it breaks everything